# Understanding cycle notation for a dihedral group and one of its subgroups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, dihedral-groups, permutation-cycles

I'm looking at an example that instructs me to consider the group:

$$
G = \langle(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (1, 8)(2, 7)(3, 6)(4, 5)\rangle \cong Dih(16)
$$

And the subgroup:

$$
H = \langle(1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6, 8)\rangle
$$

I believe these are cycles, typically written without the internal commas from what I can see in my reading of related questions here.

I've managed to decipher that $G$ is the generating set $\langle r, f \rangle$ where $r$ is a rotation and $f$ is a reflection of the octagon. So I know the full set G contains each of the nodes in [this diagram](https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/CycleGraph.html?groupURL=https://nathancarter.github.io/group-explorer/groups/D_8.group) and can see how $\langle r, f \rangle$ was turned into cycle notation.

However, I'm not sure how to parse $H$.

Is $\langle(1, 3, 5, 7)(2, 4, 6, 8)\rangle$ a specific rotation?

Should these two cycles be composed (and if so, how)?

Comment: It means the smallest subgroup that contains the element $(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)$. It is a cyclic group of order $4$, since it is generted by an element of order $4$.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I should clarify my question: what is $(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)
 $, as an element of G? How can I transform it into some combination of $r$ and $f$?

Comment: $G$ consists of all elements of $S_{8}$ that you can obtain using the elements given in the definition. One of those elements is $(1,3,5,7)(2,4,6,8)$, as it is the square of $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$, which is an element of $G$. That's what it is. To obtain this "permutation representation", recall that the dihedral group of order $16$ can be understood to be the group of rigid motions of a regular octagon; number the vertices $1$ through $8$, and see what $r$ and $f$ do to the position of the vertices: $r$ sends vertex $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$ etc. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Then look at the reflection through the axis that goes through the midpoints of the sides determined by the vertices $1$ and $8$, and the vertices $4$ and $5$.